# Transfer Excel data into a SQL Server table using file upload

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, file-upload

I need to give user a functionality of file upload where user can browse for a file and upload it to server. Data stored in the file will be extracted and inserted into a table.

Frontend code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelFileUpload" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblFileUpload" runat="server" Text="File Upload:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:FileUpload CssClass = "FileUpload" ID="fuFileUpload" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnUploadFile" runat="server" CssClass="inputButton" OnClientClick="fnStartInterval()" Text="Upload" ValidationGroup="A" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fuFileUpload" Font-Italic="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="A">*Please choose a file to upload! </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

I found this backend code for file upload but this is not working. My Excel file has 4 cols -  col1...col4. I am not sure how to map the column of Excel to table structure.

Backend code:

```
Protected Sub btnUploadFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUploadFile.Click
    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(fuFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
    Dim contentType As String = fuFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType
    Using fs As Stream = fuFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream
        Using br As New BinaryReader(fs)
            Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CType(fs.Length, Integer))
            Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
            Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
                Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO dbo..table_1 VALUES (@ContentType, @Data)"
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contentType
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Here, contenttype is being directly read from file. is there a way to read all 4 columns as it is and store it in table.

Comment: The code you posted imports the whole file as a binary object. It does no interpretation of rows and columns. I think you will have to write that code yourself. Easier if you can get them to load a csv.

Comment: Yes, of course there is. You will need to write code - and perhaps a lot of code. The database engine has no access to this file so it is the code you write in your app that must do all the work. But consider your assumptions - what must the file contain to be uploaded to the database and which table (or tables) will be updated? This is not a trivial process. And you should carefully consider how this might become a significant security flaw.

Comment: Are there headers in the excel file? Do the headers match the field names in the database?

Comment: @Mary Yes, there are header files which match the field names in database

Answer (score 0):

No promises on this but it should give you an idea on how this can be accomplished.

The DataTable is agnostic when it comes to its source so you can use the same DataTable for both the retrieved data from Excel and the insert data from to Sql Server.

```vb
Private Sub UpdateSQLServerFromExcel(FilePath As String)
    Dim dt = New DataTable()

    Using cnSource As New OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={FilePath};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";")
        Using selectCommand As New OleDbCommand("Select * From [Sheet1$];", cnSource)
            Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter
                'The following allows the .DataRowState to remain as Added (normally it is changed to Unchanged by the .Fill method)
                da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
                da.Fill(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Using cnDestination As New SqlConnection("Your Sql Server connection string")
        Using selectCommand As New SqlCommand("Select * From YourSqlTableName;", cnDestination)
            Using da As New SqlDataAdapter()
                da.SelectCommand = selectCommand
                Dim cb As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
                da.Update(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```